# Difference in result with summing and grouping in SQL

Tags: sql, group-by, sum, grouping, mariadb

In doing a little home project I found a difference in values outputted by two queries that partially should yield the exact same answer.

Its a project for calculating my used electrical energy. I translated the query below to english (original Dutch).

```
select month(measured.Date) as Month, sum(measured.used_kwh), sum(measured.used_E) from
(select DATE_FORMAT(highRate.time,'%Y-%m-%d') as Date,
max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value) + max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value) as used_kwh,
(max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value))*0.2096 + (max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value))*0.1943 as used_E
from Item8 as highRate
left join Item7 as LowRate
on highRate.Time = LowRate.Time
group by Date) as measured
group by Month;
```

Yields:
[image: Screenshot of result]

```
select MONTH(highRate.time) as Month, 
max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value) + max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value) as used_kwh,
(max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value))*0.2096 + (max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value))*0.1943 as used_E
from Item8 as highRate
left join Item7 as LowRate
on highRate.Time = LowRate.Time
group by Month;
```

Yields:
[image: Screenshot of result]

I've been trying most the afternoon to figure out what goes on here, but no result so far. Its always a difference of about 0,15 on the second column (sum(gemeten.verbruik_kwh) / verbruik_kwh).

The query above is not as need and organised as the final version as I copy these particular parts from the larger query they are part of and altered them to work with standalone.

In the screenshot below the difference is again seen, but then in the way I want it to be presented to the user. Both the "Gemeten verbruik (€)" and "Gemeten verbruik (kWh)" should have the same values in the tables.
[image: Screenshot of result of larger queries]

Comment: You're right. I changed them

Comment: It runs on Maria DB 5.5.57 on a QNAP NAS. Is this the RDBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Queries are not exactly the same. First one runs two layered aggregations which you can see with proper indentation: first at *Date* level and then second at *Month* level. The second query runs only one aggregation at *Month* level.

Likely in your data the max/min *Value* grouped by *Date* is slightly different than the max/min *Value* grouped by *Month*. Possibly there are multiple *Date* records within same *Month*.

First Query

```
SELECT month(measured.Date) AS MONTH,
       sum(measured.used_kwh),
       sum(measured.used_E)
FROM
  (SELECT DATE_FORMAT(highRate.time,'%Y-%m-%d') AS Date,

          max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value) +
          max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value) AS used_kwh,

          (max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value))*0.2096 + 
          (max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value))*0.1943 AS used_E

   FROM Item8 AS highRate
   LEFT JOIN Item7 AS LowRate ON highRate.Time = LowRate.Time
   GROUP BY Date) AS measured

GROUP BY MONTH;
```

Second Query

```
SELECT MONTH(highRate.time) AS MONTH,

       max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value) + 
       max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value) AS used_kwh,

       (max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value))*0.2096 + 
       (max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value))*0.1943 AS used_E

FROM Item8 AS highRate
LEFT JOIN Item7 AS LowRate ON highRate.Time = LowRate.Time

GROUP BY MONTH;
```

The truly equivalent nested query is aggregating both at *Month* level where outer is redundant and even the aggregate function can be replaced with `Avg()`, `Min()`, `Max()`:

```
SELECT month(measured.Date) AS MONTH,
       sum(measured.used_kwh),
       sum(measured.used_E)
FROM
      (SELECT month(DATE_FORMAT(highRate.time,'%Y-%m-%d')) AS Month,

              max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value) +
              max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value) AS used_kwh,

              (max(highRate.Value)-min(highRate.Value))*0.2096 + 
              (max(LowRate.Value)-min(LowRate.Value))*0.1943 AS used_E

       FROM Item8 AS highRate
       LEFT JOIN Item7 AS LowRate ON highRate.Time = LowRate.Time
       GROUP BY Month) AS measured

GROUP BY MONTH;
```

Comment: Duplicate records shouldn't alter the result when aggregating Daily then Monthly as opposed to simply aggregating monthly.  If a value goes Down from one day the next, however, that's going to make a difference.

Comment: Hmmm...I made no mention of duplicate records. I mentioned *multiple* records. Really I am saying that this is a data question as max/min daily values will not always match max/min monthly values.

Comment: I agree, data behaviour issue.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your data there are several possible answers.

With a large enough volume of data, this can happen when using Floating Point data types.  It's a long topic, but Floating point data types Do Not represent decimal numbers infinitely well and can easily accrue significant rounding errors *(often known as bruising)*.

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

What is the result of your inner query in your first example?  Could that show you the source of any rounding error?

***More likely, however,*** there are incongruities in your data.  Look for rows where the `value` goes DOWN when compared to the previous record.

It looks like you're using `MySQL` which makes it messy, but still possible, to check for such rows...

```
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN this.value < next.value THEN next.value - this.value END)  AS increases,
    SUM(CASE WHEN this.value > next.value THEN this.value - next.value END)  AS decreases
FROM
    Item8    AS this
INNER JOIN
    Item8    AS next
       ON next.time = (SELECT MIN(Item8.time) FROM Item8 WHERE Item8.time < this.time)
```

Or alternatively, try this and just eye-ball it...

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(highRate.time,'%Y-%m-%d')   AS Date,
    MIN(highRate.Value)                     AS HighRateMinValue,
    MAX(highRate.Value)                     AS HighRateMaxValue,
    MIN(LowRate.Value)                      AS LowRateMinValue,
    MAX(LowRate.Value)                      AS LowRateMaxValue
FROM
    Item8   AS highRate
LEFT JOIN
    Item7   AS LowRate
        ON  highRate.Time = LowRate.Time
GROUP BY
    Date
ORDER BY
    Date
```

If you ever see a LowRate**Min**Value that is ***lower*** than a preceding day's LowRate**Max**Value, that's your 'problem'.

This matters when you have data like this...

```
   MAX( {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4} ) - MIN( {1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4} )
=>
   4 - 1
=> 
   3
```

Compared to...

```
   [ MAX( {1, 2, 3} ) - MIN( {1, 2, 3} ) ]   +    [ MAX( {2, 3, 4} ) - MIN( {2, 3, 4} ) ]
=>
   [3 - 1] + [4 - 2]
=> 
   4
```

On an unrelated note, for performance reasons, you are probably better combing the results from each table After aggregation, rather than a JOIN Before the aggregation...

```
SELECT
    COALESCE(highRate.month, low_rate.month)                                            AS month,
    COALESCE(highRate.used_kwh, 0)          + COALESCE(lowRate.used_kwh, 0)             AS used_kwh,
    COALESCE(highRate.used_kwh, 0) * 0.2096 + COALESCE(lowRate.used_kwh, 0) * 0.1943    AS used_E
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(Item8.time,'%Y-%m-01')    AS month,
        MAX(Item8.value) - MIN(Item8.value)   AS used_kwh
    FROM
        Item8
    GROUP BY
        day
)
    AS highRate
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(Item7.time,'%Y-%m-01')    AS month,
        MAX(Item7.value) - MIN(Item7.value)   AS used_kwh
    FROM
        Item7
    GROUP BY
        day
)
    AS lowRate
        ON lowRate.month = highRate.month
```

This will allow the query planner to much more quickly identify the MIN and MAX values for each table *(or range of rows for the table)*, and significantly reduce the number of rows that ever need to be joined.

This will also protect you if there are rows in LowRate that are not in HighRate, as well as cases where there are multiple entries for the same time.

***EDIT:***

The aggregate-then-join version of aggregating to day first, then month.

```
SELECT
    MONTH(COALESCE(highRate.day, low_rate.day))                                                   AS month,
    COALESCE(SUM(highRate.used_kwh), 0)          + COALESCE(SUM(lowRate.used_kwh), 0)             AS used_kwh,
    COALESCE(SUM(highRate.used_kwh), 0) * 0.2096 + COALESCE(SUM(lowRate.used_kwh), 0) * 0.1943    AS used_E
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(Item8.time,'%Y-%m-%d')    AS day,
        MAX(Item8.value) - MIN(Item8.value)   AS used_kwh
    FROM
        Item8
    GROUP BY
        day
)
    AS highRate
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
    SELECT
        DATE_FORMAT(Item7.time,'%Y-%m-%d')    AS day,
        MAX(Item7.value) - MIN(Item7.value)   AS used_kwh
    FROM
        Item7
    GROUP BY
        day
)
    AS lowRate
        ON lowRate.day = highRate.day 
GROUP BY
   month
```

***EDIT:***

An even shorter approach (to avoid the `JOIN`s and `COALESCE`s altogether)...

```
SELECT
    month,

    SUM(high)                                 AS used_kwh_high,
                         SUM(low)             AS used_kwh_low,
    SUM(high)          + SUM(low)             AS used_kwh,

    SUM(high) * 0.2096                        AS used_E_high,
                         SUM(low) * 0.1943    AS used_E_low,
    SUM(high) * 0.2096 + SUM(low) * 0.1943    AS used_E
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-01') AS month, MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS high, 0 AS low FROM Item8 GROUP BY month
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-01') AS month, 0 AS high, MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS low FROM Item7 GROUP BY month
)
    combined_rates
GROUP BY
    month
```

And the Day then Month aggregation version...

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT(day,'%Y-%m-01') AS month,

    SUM(high)                                 AS used_kwh_high,
                         SUM(low)             AS used_kwh_low,
    SUM(high)          + SUM(low)             AS used_kwh,

    SUM(high) * 0.2096                        AS used_E_high,
                         SUM(low) * 0.1943    AS used_E_low,
    SUM(high) * 0.2096 + SUM(low) * 0.1943    AS used_E
FROM
(
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d') AS day, MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS high, 0 AS low FROM Item8 GROUP BY day
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATE_FORMAT(time,'%Y-%m-%d') AS day, 0 AS high, MAX(value) - MIN(value) AS low FROM Item7 GROUP BY day
)
    combined_rates
GROUP BY
    month
```

Comment: You should really also add `COALESCE()` aroudn the daily or monthly values being added together (in case of a day or a month that has either no highRate or no lowRate values).

Comment: Typos corrected and `COALESCE()` added.  should be robust now I believe.

Comment: I've just realised another potential problem for you...  if your data is `{1,2,3}` for day1 then `{4,5,6}` for day2?  `MAX({1,2,3}) - MIN({1,2,3})` = `2`.  `MAX({4,5,6}) - MIN({4,5,6})` = `2` => Total of 4?  `MAX({1,2,3,4,5,6}) - MIN({1,2,3,4,5,6})` = `5`.  The whole approach only works if you are ***guaranteed*** to have a record at the start of a day with *the exact same value* as the previous day ended.  If you can't guarantee that, you need a new approach.  Which I don't want to do in MySQL ;)

Answer (score 0):

@MatBailie:
Sticking in the first method with cases yielded:

```
increases: NULL; decreases: 18323.261840820312
```

The second "eye-ball" method resulted in:

```
Date    HighRateMinValue    HighRateMaxValue    LowRateMinValue LowRateMaxValue
2017-11-16  1358.1080322265625  1362.0860595703125  1252.5179443359375  1252.7440185546875
2017-11-17  1362.0860595703125  1370.177978515625   1252.761962890625   1254.592041015625
2017-11-18  1370.177978515625   1370.177978515625   1254.6280517578125  1262.7679443359375
2017-11-19  1370.177978515625   1370.177978515625   1262.7840576171875  1272.72900390625
2017-11-20  1370.177978515625   1375.876953125  1272.7469482421875  1274.7969970703125
2017-11-21  1375.876953125  1383.2359619140625  1274.81298828125    1277.541015625
```

I think this all looks fine, or did i miss the point?

Comment: There's a gap...  16th, Low Rate, Ends at 1252.7**440185546875**.  17th, Low Rate, Starts at 1252.7**61962890625**.  The value of this gap "between" the days is "ignored" by the DayThenMonth approach, but is "counted" by the "StraightToMonth" approach.

Comment: And another the next day...And the next day...  In fact they're all in the LowRate.  I believe the `LEFT JOIN` is the problem.  Where there is a value in `Item7` there isn't always a value in `Item8` for the same `time`. This means that not all of your `LowRate` values are being included in your aggregation.  You either need a `FULL OUTER JOIN` or you need to aggregate first, then join....

Comment: Try out, and compare the results of, the last two queries in my answer.

Comment: I've added to my answer the shortest possible code *(that I can think of)* to get the correct result.